# The column attribute "ORDINAL_POSITION" is not valid [Import and Export Wizard - Visual FoxPro ProviderDescriptors.xml SSIS]

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, odbc, visual-foxpro

I am trying to **sync a Visual FoxPro database to a SQL Server database**.
I am using the **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard** (from SQL Server Data Tools).

When I click "**Edit Mappings...**" I first had 4 errors with the same problem, then I changed a few values in **ProviderDescriptors.xml** and ended up with this:

```
<dtm:ColumnSchemaAttributes
    NameColumnName = "COLUMN_NAME"
    OrdinalPositionColumnName="ORDINAL_POSITION"
    DataTypeColumnName = "TYPE_NAME"
    MaximumLengthColumnName = "LENGTH"
    NumericPrecisionColumnName = "PRECISION"
    NumericScaleColumnName = "SCALE"
    NullableColumnName="NULLABLE"
    NumberOfColumnRestrictions="4"
/>
```

Now the only error is on `OrdinalPositionColumnName`
Error: `The column attribute "ORDINAL_POSITION" is not valid`

**Which value to use for `OrdinalPositionColumnName` (when using the Visual FoxPro ODBC driver)?**

Thanks for helping!

Comment: There isn't a Foxpro ODBC driver (after version 6.x). Use VFPOLEDB driver instead.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thanks for your reply! I couldn't use `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro` because it crashes when I select that and hit `Properties...`

Comment: Well I have never used it with SSIS. I always write my to-from SQL server codes myself in VFP or C#, Go, ... You might try VFPOLEDB in Linked servers. (BTW it is an 32 bits driver, under 64 bits it wouldn't work).

Comment: My MS SQl Server is 64 bits so that would probably not work, how do I write a C# program to import a FVP free table database to SQL Server?

Comment: You could use SqlBulkCopy class. I can give you sample code as an answer if you like.

Comment: And BTW, if you would use this via VFP, then I created and uploaded an activex for it on foxite.com (search for SqlBulkCopy and SbcHelper).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample:

```
void Main()
{
    string sqlConnectionString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=Test";
    // c:\MyDataFolder\myTable.dbf
    string dataPath = @"c:\MyDataFolder";
    string tableName = @"MyTable";

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); // just for timing the sample run
    sw.Start();

    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=" + dataPath))
    using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"select * from {tableName}", cn);
        SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(scn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null);

        // Needed if VFP-SQL Server tables' field count or names are different
        // ie: LName in VFP might be LastName in SQL server
        // or VFP might have 10 fields when SQL server 8
        // VFP column names on left, SQL server column names on right
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Category", "[Category]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Activity", "[Activity]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("PersonId", "[PersonId]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("FirstName", "[FirstName]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("MidName", "[MidName]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("LastName", "[LastName]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "[Email]");

        cn.Open();
        scn.Open();

        // Since this is a sample, instead of wrting to a table
        // creating and writing to a global temporary table
        // You can see this table's data, connecting to the same database (global temp)
        SqlCommand createTemp = new SqlCommand();
        createTemp.CommandText = @"create table ##PersonData 
  (
    [Id] int identity primary key,
    [Category] varchar(50), 
    [Activity] varchar(50) default 'NullOlmasin', 
    [PersonId] varchar(50), 
    [FirstName] varchar(50), 
    [MidName] varchar(50), 
    [LastName] varchar(50), 
    [Email] varchar(50)
  )";
        createTemp.Connection = scn;
        createTemp.ExecuteNonQuery();

        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        sbc.NotifyAfter = 100000;
        sbc.BatchSize = 1000;
        sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
        sbc.DestinationTableName = "##PersonData";

        sbc.SqlRowsCopied += (sender, e) =>
          {
              Console.WriteLine("-- Copied {0} rows to {1}.[{2} milliseconds]",
          e.RowsCopied,
          ((SqlBulkCopy)sender).DestinationTableName,
          sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
          };

        sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);

        if (!rdr.IsClosed) { rdr.Close(); }

        cn.Close();
        scn.Close();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Done in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late but I came across your question while searching for the answer myself, and I wanted to document it here in case there is anyone else in my position in the future that searches this issue and finds this page.

The answer is Radix

in context, it looks like this:

```
    <dtm:ColumnSchemaAttributes
        NameColumnName = "COLUMN_NAME"
        OrdinalPositionColumnName="Radix"
        DataTypeColumnName = "TYPE_NAME"
        MaximumLengthColumnName = "LENGTH"
        NumericPrecisionColumnName = "PRECISION"
        NumericScaleColumnName = "SCALE"
        NullableColumnName="NULLABLE"
        NumberOfColumnRestrictions="4"
    />
```